# Tiling the unit square with right triangles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, recreational-mathematics, discrete-geometry, packing-problem

What's the minimal number of distinct right angled triangles needed to tile a unit square? I suspect it cannot be done in less than four, thus here are the solutions for $4$ triangles so far:

[image]

Define a unit square $ABCD$; then the three distinct constructions so far are:

1. Connect two opposite corners ($\overline{AC}$), and place a fifth point ($E$) anywhere on some side ($\overline{BC}$) of the square. Connect the fifth point with the remaining available point ($A$) and draw a perpendicular line  ($\overline{EF}$) from it to the diagonal line. You now have $4$ distinct triangles tiling the square.
2. Place a fifth point ($E$) anywhere on some side ($\overline{BC}$)  of the square except on the middle point ($P$) of that side. Connect it with the two points of the opposing side ($\overline{DA}$) and draw a perpendicular line ($\overline{DF}$ or $\overline{AF}$) from any of those two points to the opposing line segment. You now have $4$ distinct triangles tiling the square.
3. [Oscar Lanzi's construction](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2312455); From $A$ draw a line segment to a point $E$ anywhere on side $\overline{BC}$. Construct the perpendicular to $\overline{AE}$ through $E$ which intersects side $\overline{CD}$ at $F$. Finish the division by drawing $AF$. You now have $4$ distinct triangles tiling the square.

---

> Do these constructions contain all valid solutions to tile the
>   unit square with $4$ distinct right angle triangles? Or are there some other ways missing?
>
> The goal is to find all valid solutions for this simple problem, and prove no more exist.
>
> But I'm not sure how can one tell whether we have all the solutions contained in these constructions so far or not?

---

Follow up question; is it possible that there exists a solution among the solutions such that all four triangles have all side lengths rational?

Since I stumbled upon [a tweet](https://twitter.com/aap03102/status/777081612400005120) showing $5$ Pythagorean triples packed in a square; If that square were scaled down to a unit square, we would have a solution with $5$ triangles that have all sides rational.

> Is it possible to do it in $4$?
>
> Pack four rational distinct triangles in a unit square?
>
> I suppose this can be shown false if all constructions were found and
>   shown to not contain such a solution. So far, these three
>   constructions seem to not contain such a solution, if I'm not
>   mistaken.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution with four triangles later incorporated into the question.  Start with square $ABCD$. From$A$ draw a line segment to a point $E$ on side $BC$. Construct the perpendicular to $AE$ through $E$ which intersects side $CD$ at $F$.  Finish the division by drawing $AF$.  This must be distinct from the cases given above because only one vertex of the square is used for triangle vertices with acute angles.

Comment: Added to the constructions.